# Can I declare War without losing Honor?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

The question basically says it all.

I am the female ruler of my own Faction, the Kingdom of Metal. I begin my Wars by speaking to another Jarl or Count whatever and demand them to surrender, leading into a fight.

That results in a decleration of War and I loose Honor, even if the opposite Faction is much larger than me.

Is there any "good" or "political correct" way to declare a War?

Comment: Just wondering, is the gender of your character actually relevant to the question?

Comment: I was not sure about it, so I added it. It plays a role very often

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can talk to your minister to send an envoy, who's gonna declare a political war on your enemy.

From the inofficial [wiki](http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_a_new_kingdom#The_Minister_and_Ruling_Options)

> "By talking to this minister you can conduct many different affairs of
> state. Diplomats can be dispatched to the other factions, performing
> such actions as declaring war..."

Sadly, it would still cause problem with your honor rating and lord relations. It only prevents you from losing relationship with city/village/lord you wolud have to harras otherwise.

In order to declare war without consequence, you have to wait for event informing about border incident.

Comment: You're most welcome ;)